# Getting Success Results from $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the success results from jquery/ajax. I've tried to call an outside function to make sure.. setting the result as global is.. global? I get how scope works, but it doesn't seem to work here. So maybe I don't understand scope regarding jquery? The following is where I'm at now - lots of trial and error. In this case, using an alert on data['test'] gives me the result I'm looking for, but when I call setSession() setting session_results does not work.

*edit - I just noticed that the script doesn't wait for $.post to finish, so there's my problem. Callback functions, according to other questions asked around here. Anyone have an example or recommendation? Otherwise, this thread can be closed.

**edit - Thanks Cuong Le.

```
// SESSION
var session_results;
function setSession(data) {
    session_results = data;
}
function SESSION() {
    $.post(
        "handler.php",
        { get_session: "get_session" },
        function(data) {
            alert(data['test']);
            setSession(data);
        },
        "json"
    );
}

SESSION();
alert(session_results['test']);
```

Comment: I just noticed that the script doesn't appear to wait for $.post to finish. Looks like I have to reorganize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait until the ajax post is done then you are able to alert `alert(session_results);` correctly, use promise concept in jquery:

```
var session_results;
function setSession(data) {
    session_results = data;
}

function SESSION() {
    var promise = $.post(
        "handler.php",
        { get_session: "get_session" },
        function(data) {
            alert(data['test']);
            setSession(data);
        },
        "json"
    );

    return promise;
}

var result = SESSION();

result.done(function(){
    alert(session_results);
});
```

For more corrective, you should use the new syntax of jquery ajax by using `done` function:

```
function SESSION() {
    var promise = $.post( "handler.php",  { get_session: "get_session" })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        alert(data['test']);
                        setSession(data);
                    });

    return promise;
}
```

Comment: How would I include "json" in that, or does it handle that automatically? I'm guessing ( "handler.php",  { get_session: "get_session" }, "json")

Comment: @Daniel: it's handle automatically, you should read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for more detail

Comment: Yeah. I've been reading that. The second to last example is where I started to return json encoded results. But I got stuck with, as Shahar points out, the asynchronous nature of AJAX (har har), and didn't realize it. :-P The .done thing, I feel stupid for not noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because AJAX stands for *Asynchronous* JavaScript and XML. It isn't guaranteed to be finished by your next call. So what you can do instead is:

```
var session_results;
function setSession(data) {
    session_results = data;
}
function SESSION() {
    $.post(
        "handler.php",
        { get_session: "get_session" },
        function(data) {
            alert(data['test']);
            setSession(data);
            alert(session_results['test']); //moved to here
        },
        "json"
    );
}

SESSION();
```

Or you can use `$.ajax` with `async` off.

Comment: Years later wanted to say thanks for this without being snarky. I was a dummy learning things beyond my abilities. :P